# Different code completion in editor vs console

Tags: python, pycharm, code-completion

versions:

```
macOS Monterey 12.5
PyCharm        2022.1.4
python         3.10.5
```

I'm trying to display the suggestions for [faker.Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/fakerclass.html) attributes which are showing in the debugger console and not in the editor.

Editor view:

[image: editor]

Console view:

[image: console]

and this is not the first time I experience this annoying behavior. Most libraries work fine everywhere though.

Comment: You probably have different environments on terminal and pycharm. Run `which python ` in terminal to know which are you using. Then need pycharm to use the same, [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003509599-Different-Python-version-in-Terminal-and-PyCharm-despite-using-the-very-same-venv-and-path) may help

Comment: How exactly is the debugger running a different environment than the editor?  do you even know how the debugger console works?